# How to find out a users path to conversion in Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, analytics

I want to find a method by which I can find out that how a conversion has been made.

I.e:

1. a user, came from Google click on home page
2. then move to the category page
3. then category 2
4. then move to products 1
5. And then buy it.

But, I can't do this in Google Analytics. Could you guys let me know that how I can do this so, that I can backtrack the consumer flow and his journey on the website?

Answer (score 2):

In my knowledge, a Goal in GA should give you required relevant data, but if you want very specific user then different strategy need to be find.

Goal Strategy:

Let's say if the website structure is:

Home >> Cat 1 >> Cat 2 >> Product >> Cart >> Checkout

You could create a goal and it will give you data like:

Home (100 Users) >> Cat 1 (90 Users) >> Cat 2 (60 Users) >> Product (50 Users) >> Cart (20 Users) >> Checkout (5 Users)

Comment: and how to create goal like this in Google Analytics

Comment: GA >> Choose the account >> Admin >> View >> Goals >> + New Goals. To view the goal: GA >> Choose Account >> Conversions >> Goals >> Funnel Visualization

Comment: But majority of the thing is in not provided keywords how it can be mapped to the keywords

Comment: Yes, that's the hardest part in GS majority of the keywords being not provided. You need to rely on other tools like Webmasters etc. It's very hard to map user journey from keyword to purchase in very simple way.

Comment: Bummer! How we can connect to that from webmaster to google analytics

Comment: You may not, understand that in general. GA can give you out x orders how may came from Organic, Social, PPC etc. And use Webmasters to see your ranking in general. Meaning they are different tools and they give different statistics. Just to give you a hint, this is where digital analytics comes into play.

Comment: Now that Google is no sending keywords in the referrer, there is no way to associate organic search keywords with conversions.  Not even if you connect Google Search Console data to Google Analytics.  :(